# Multiple labels for 1 point

Tags: arcgis-10.0, labeling

I have map points for schools in a district. I want to label the map ID and the name of the school on the map. I have the map ID labeled within the point symbol but I want the school name outside of that. Is this possible without manually putting in a text box for the school name? Using ArcMap 10

Comment: in which software?

Comment: I am using ArcMap 10

Answer (score 7):

You could use an Expression for the label and insert new line characters to create a stacked label.
"Map Id: " & [MapID] & vbCrLf & "Name: " & [SchoolName]

See http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s800000027000000.htm

Answer (score 7):

another method (without having 2 layers) is to "define classes of features and label each class differently"
[image: multilabel]
just set up the style for your first label.
Then hit add.
It will duplicate that style. (you can then change it to whaterver you want).

Comment: I tried this and found some inconsistent labelling.  Some points had stacked labels and sometimes the two labels were side by side (appearing concatenated).

Comment: @KevinMayall, you may have to play with placement options... more an art than science, TBH.

Comment: I use it most often with a box label offset by 20 points or such, then the other label may be no box bold with no offset. you are right play with it

Comment: @KevinMayall, Yes I had this problem too but I got it to work by going to placement properties button, Label Position tab, then clicked "user-defined zones" (if you are using maplex labeling) and then telling arc which place I wanted to labels to go myself in order of priority.

Answer (score 5):

I've done similar by having multiple instances of the layer.  Add the point layer twice, and have one instance with the mapID label, the other with the school name label.

Comment: @Bart mark this as an answer then

Comment: This works, but can lead to a long table of contents with unnecessarily-duplicated layers. Brad Nesom's and KevinMayall's answers aren't difficult to implement, and prevent the layer duplication.

Answer (score 0):

In the labeling tab, go to label field, click the expression button to the right of the field, click on the first label (f1 is the default), then click the second, and click append. Then click the verify button to make sure you did it correctly.Then click OK!